# How to preview the image if it is set as wallpaper programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have setted 1 image as mywallpaper from Gridview images,but before that i need preview of that image before setting it as wallpaper like home screen image

Note: Preview of homescreen image

Answer (score 1):

Create a XML file for the preview

displayfulimage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llFullImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgvFullImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.65" />   


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtImageName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:text="Image Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Check the following code. It may be of some help...
Things to note ::: 1. getView() 2. onItemClick()

```
public class MembersGallery extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    GridView gvMembers;
    int values[]={R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,R.drawable.e,R.drawable.f};
    ImageView im;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.memberimages);

        gvMembers =(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gvMembers);
        MyAdapter myad = new MyAdapter();
        gvMembers.setAdapter(myad);
        gvMembers.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return values.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            im=new ImageView(MembersGallery.this);
            im.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
            im.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
            im.setImageResource(values[position]);

            return im;
        }           
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Toast.makeText(this," Clicked", 30).show();

        ImageView rImage = new ImageView(this);
        rImage.setImageResource(values[arg2]);

        displayFullImage(rImage,250,250);           
    }


    private void displayFullImage(ImageView im2, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ImageView tempImageView = im2;

        AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.displayfulimage,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.llFullImage));
        ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imgvFullImage);
        image.setImageDrawable(tempImageView.getDrawable());
        imageDialog.setView(layout);
        imageDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });
        imageDialog.create();
        imageDialog.show();     
    }

}
```